# What do the words "of old" mean in Deuteronomy 32:7 and Nehemiah 12:46?

Tags: word-study

Deauteronomy 32:7 ASV
Remember the days **of old**, Consider the years of many generations: Ask thy father, and he will show thee; Thine elders, and they will tell thee.

Nehemiah 12:46 ASV
For in the days of David and Asaph **of old** there was a chief of the singers, and songs of praise and thanksgiving unto God

What does "**of old**" mean in these verses?

Answer (score 1):

As Perry said - meaning depends on context.

Looking at the context:

Deuteronomy 31:30 through 32:43 is known as the song of Moses.
32:1 is the beginning of the song.
Verses 1 - 4 Moses praises God.
Verses 5-6 Moses says:

> 5 They are corrupt and not his children;
> to their shame they are a warped and crooked generation.
> 6 Is this the way you repay the Lord,
> you foolish and unwise people?
> Is he not your Father, your Creator,
> who made you and formed you?

Moses moves from "Is he not your Father, your Creator" reminding them of who God is and who they are to reminding them of how good God has been to them. Moses starts his passage of reminding them of what God has done with:

> 7 Remember the days of old;
> consider the generations long past.
> Ask your father and he will tell you,
> your elders, and they will explain to you.

In this context "Remember the days of old" means that Moses is asking the people to remember the past. So, "days of old" = the past. Moses calls on them to ask people who are old enough to remember these times as teachers and witnesses to the events.

Moses wants the people to recognize who God is and live accordingly.

Nehemiah 12:46 has a similar context. The walls of Jerusalem are being dedicated. The author is remembering how things were "long ago" or in the "days of old".

Answer (score 0):

In Nehemiah 12:46 it is מִקֶּ֑דֶם which is מִן (nun dropped) meaning *from, of* prefixed to קֶדֶם.

> For long ago in the days of David and Asaph there were directors of the singers, and there were songs of praise and thanksgiving to God.
> (Neh. 12:46, ESV)

In Deut. 32:7 it is עוֹלָ֔ם.

```
         Remember the days of old; 
  consider the years of many generations; 
              ask your father, and he will show you, 
  your elders, and they will tell you. 
        8       When the Most High gave to the nations their inheritance, 
  when he divided mankind, 
              he fixed the borders of the peoples 
  according to the number of the sons of God. 
          (Deut. 32:7–8)
```

Their meanings depends on the context. Both of the verse have a clear context.  Neh. 12:46 in the verse and Deut. 32:7 in verse 8.

**Figure 1**. Senses of קֶדֶם in the MT (generated with Logos Bible Software).

[image]

**Figure 2**. Senses of עוֹלָ֔ם in the MT

[image]